# First Variation of Dyson Series/Magnus Expansion

Tags: lie-groups, mp.mathematical-physics, lie-algebras, oc.optimization-and-control

Given the matrix differential equation $\frac{dU_t}{dt}=A_t U_t$ there are at least two ways to write a formal solution. Both the Dyson series: $U_t = \mathcal{T} e^{\int_{0}^{t} A_t dt}$ and the Magnus expansion (see http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.5488) formally solve this equation for $U_t$ given $A_t$.

Is there a way to use either expansion (or any other method!) to find the first variation of $Re(Tr(U_T^{\dagger}O))$ for a given $T$ and $O$ and solve for extrema. I mean to say:

Solve $\frac{d}{d \epsilon} Re(Tr(U_{T, \epsilon}^{\dagger}O)) \bigg|_{\epsilon=0} =0$, $\forall B_t$. Where $U_{T,\epsilon}$ is the solution to the original equation after $A_t \mapsto A_t + \epsilon B_t$ and $B_0=B_T = 0$.

Comment: Using the so called Duhamel formula suffices.